# Altering the CSS of a span with a div by class inside $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class=module onclick="systemMenuRevealModule(this)"><span>Dashboard</span> 
    <div class=module_function><span>Performance</span></div>
    <div class=module_function><span>Alerts</span></div>
</div>
<div class=module onclick="systemMenuRevealModule(this)"><span>Favorites</span>
    <div class=module_function><span>Dashboard</span></div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    function systemMenuRevealModule(el){
        $('.module_function span').css('display', 'none');
        $(this).find(".module_function span").css('display', 'block');


    }
</script>
```

I am trying to reveal only the span's that are within the div being clicked. This is part of a menu structure code. I am trying to make this work without IDs, to make the code more universal. I don't see any errors in console, and nothing happens?

Answer (score 5):

That's because `this` in the click handler refers to the `window` object not the clicked element. You are passing the clicked element to the handler, use it:

```
function systemMenuRevealModule(el) {
    $('.module_function span').css('display', 'none');
    $(el).find(".module_function span").css('display', 'block');
}
```

An alternative without using `onclick` attribute:

```
var $spans = $('.module_function span');
$('.module').on('click', function() {
     // `this` here refers to the clicked element
     $spans.hide();
     $(this).find(".module_function span").show();
});
```